# Change ACF dynamic fields to European format in Generateblocks

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

How can I format a numeric value according to the European formatting convention, which uses commas as thousands separators and periods as decimal separators instead of the US standard formatting convention, which uses commas as decimal separators and periods as thousands separators?
They are dynamic ACF values of type number.
I already solved it with Bricks and ACF but the same solution does not work with Generateblocks.
I used the filter:

```
function custom_format_european_number($value, $post_id, $field) {
    // Check if ACF field is of numeric type
    if ($field['type'] === 'number') {
        // Check if the value is numeric
        if (is_numeric($value)) {
            // Round the value to 2 decimal places
            $rounded_value = round($value, 2);
            // Check if the value has decimal places
            if (floor($rounded_value) == $rounded_value) {
                return number_format($rounded_value, 0, ',', '.'); // Format as an integer
            } else {
                return number_format($rounded_value, 2, ',', '.'); // Format with 2 decimal places
            }
        }
    }
    return $value;
}
add_filter('acf/format_value', 'custom_format_european_number', 10, 3);
```

Thank you very much for your help and best regards to the community.

I have tried with the previous code to make the change to European format.
This code is a WordPress code snippet that defines a function called `custom_format_european_number` and hooks it to a filter named `acf/format_value`. The purpose of this code is to format a numerical value according to the European formatting convention, which uses commas as thousands separators and periods as decimal separators, as opposed to the standard U.S. formatting convention, which uses periods as decimal separators and commas as thousands separators.
It does not seem to work with Generateblocks.

Comment: The code given above should work. Ensure that you are targeting the correct ACF field name or key in your code. Double-check that the field you want to format is named correctly in both your code and your ACF settings.

Comment: That filter that I have set is typical of acf, it can be seen in the following [documentation](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/acf-format_value/): 
What's more, it is working perfectly for me with Bricks builder but not with Generateblocks.
Exactly this filter does not point to the correct ACF field name or key in the code but applies to all fields.